# upload compressed file on S3 -> download with CloudFront -> when extract, different directory depth

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I uploaded a compressed file (extension: tar.gz) and often download it by using cloudfront url. But, whenever extracted after downloading, there are cases where the directory structure changes...

unlike the basic file structure, there are cases where a compressed file with one more depth is downloaded..

Does anyone know why this is happening? If you have, I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: This is almost assuredly an issue with using tar to create the file in the first place.  Failing that, do you have evidence the file is changing (a changing hash, perhaps)?

Comment: it was cloudfront cashing problem. after changing behavior tab's "CashingOptimized" to "CashingDisabled", it was solved.